# How to get Addition of multiple textbox's values in another single textbox using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, textbox

Newbie in jquery, need some help with this description.

Suppose, I have 1 textbox that contain the result of Addition of another 2 textbox's.

```
<input type="text class="tb1">
<input type="text class="tb2">
<input type="text class="result" id="result1">
```

like this.

Suppose I have 5 textbox's that contain their individual 2 textbox's addition results.
Each Result textbox generate result automatically using jquery script.
So, I have 5 result textbox's with their respective addition result.

Now, I want to sum of the values in all 5 result texbox's again in another textbox when i click on checkbox automatically by using jquery or javascript script.

How can I achive this task ?
refer image for understanding of question. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFF46.jpg

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Does you have dynamic number of checkboxes? or Only five?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number 5 of the text boxes remains the same here is a solution for your problem. ( Without validations )

```js
$("#add").click(function() {

  $("#result1").val(parseInt($("#box1").val()) + parseInt($("#box2").val()));
  $("#result2").val(parseInt($("#box3").val()) + parseInt($("#box4").val()));
  $("#result3").val(parseInt($("#box5").val()) + parseInt($("#box6").val()));
  $("#result4").val(parseInt($("#box7").val()) + parseInt($("#box8").val()));
  $("#result5").val(parseInt($("#box9").val()) + parseInt($("#box10").val()));

  
});

$( "#final-check" ).change(function() {
  var finalResult = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      finalResult = finalResult + parseInt($("#result" + i).val());
    }

  $("#final-result").val(finalResult);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="box1">
    </td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="box2">
    </td>
    <td>=</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="result1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="box3">
    </td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="box4">
    </td>
    <td>=</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="result2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="box5">
    </td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="box6">
    </td>
    <td>=</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="result3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="box7">
    </td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="box8">
    </td>
    <td>=</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="result4">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="box9">
    </td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="box10">
    </td>
    <td>=</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="result5">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="add">add</button>
<input type="text" id="final-result">
<input type="checkbox" id="final-check">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any number of text boxes and get your results.

```
<div>
  <input type="text" class="textBox" value="0">
  <input type="text" class="textBox" value="0">
  <input type="text" class="resultBox" value="0">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="textBox" value="0">
  <input type="text" class="textBox" value="0">
  <input type="text" class="resultBox" value="0">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="textBox" value="0">
  <input type="text" class="textBox" value="0">
  <input type="text" class="resultBox" value="0">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="textBox" value="0">
  <input type="text" class="textBox" value="0">
  <input type="text" class="resultBox" value="0">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="textBox" value="0">
  <input type="text" class="textBox" value="0">
  <input type="text" class="resultBox" value="0">
</div>


<div>
  <input type="text" id="mainTotBox" value="0">
 </div>

$(".textBox").on("change", function(){
  var total = 0;
  var thisInput = this;
  $(this).closest("div").find("input[class='textBox']").each(function(index, inputEle){
    total += window.parseInt($(inputEle).val());
    $(thisInput).closest("div").find(".resultBox").val(total);
  });
  var mainTot = 0;
  $(".resultBox").each(function(index, inputEle){
    mainTot += window.parseInt($(inputEle).val());
  });
  $("#mainTotBox").val(mainTot);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text class="tb">
<input type="text class="tb">
<input type="text class="tb">
<input type="text class="tb">
<input type="text class="tb">
<input type="text class="result" id="result">

<script>
var result=0;

// Loop thru each input field that has class tb, take its numeric value
// and add it to result
function AddEmUp()
{
   $("input.tb").each( 
   function() 
   {
     result=result+Number( $(this).val() );
   });

   // Display the result in input box with id=result
   $("#result").val( result);
}
// Execute AddEmUp when any one of the input fields with class tb is clicked
$("input.tb").click( AddEmUp );
</result>
```